# How to add things to a menustrip programatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, menustrip

I want to add whatever is written in a textbox to a menustrip. In the File > Recent Searches thing I have.

How can I do programatically? And can I assign an event handler dynamically so that when a user clicks on X item in that subfolder, the text is copied BACK to the textbox?

**EDIT: How can I programatically call on the folder Busquedas Recientes (in pic)**

[image]

Comment: Which IDE or platform/language are you using? (for example, C with Win32 API, C# on .NET Framework, or etc.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this by taking advantage of the `object sender` parameter in the event handler.  Most of this is off the top of my head so I'm only *guessing* that it will compile but it should get you started.

```
void AddMenuItem(string text, string action)
{
   ToolStripMenuItem item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
   item.Text = text;
   item.Click += new EventHandler(item_Click);
   item.Tag = action;

   //first option, inserts at the top
   //historyMenu.Items.Add(item);

   //second option, should insert at the end
   historyMenuItem.DropDownItems.Insert(historyMenuItem.DropDownItems.Count, item);
}

private void someHistoryMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ToolStripMenuItem menuItem = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;

   string args = menuItem.Tag.ToString();

   YourSpecialAction(args);
}
```

Comment: The first method kinda works. The search is being added but on the top most level. I need it to be added into this heirarchy: File > RecentSearches > THINGS GO HERE. Any help?

Answer (score 5):

It's rather straight forward. You can do the following:

```
ToolStripMenuItem menuItem

foreach (string text in collectionOfText)
{
    ToolStripMenuItem foo = new ToolStripMenuItem(text);
    foo.Click += new EventHandler(ClickEvent);
    menuItem.DropDownItems.Add(foo);
}
```

Subsequently, if the Click event doesn't work (I had trouble where it wouldn't detect the correct menu item), you can add a "DropDownItemClicked" event to the menuItem. and to get the text of the item you clicked you do:

```
private void DropedDownItemClickedEvent(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    string text = e.ClickedItem.Text;
}
```

I hope that helps.

Oh and don't forget to remove the Event as well. I forgot to do that with all the dynamic menus I had created and somehow ended up eating half my memory. :D

Comment: Lol. :P +1 for the last comment. Saved me another question xD