# Programmatically Adding Items To A Menu Strip?

Tags: c#, winforms, menustrip

Let's say I have a WinForm that has a menu strip in it.  Let's say one of the items of this menu strip is named Cars.

Whenever I open my WinForm, I want to add a subitem under Cars for every car in a table.

Is this possible to do with code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
string[] cars = new string[]{"Volvo", "SAAB"};

foreach (var car in cars)
{
    ToolStripItem subItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(car);
    carsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(subItem);
}
```

**Note:** If you add an event to the subItem, make sure you unsubscribe to that event if you are refreshing the list repeatedly, otherwise you will have a memory leak.

**Note2:** If you have many items you should use [`DropDownItems.AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownitem.dropdownitems.aspx) instead for performance reasons.

Comment: For some reason, DropDownItems isn't an available option from intellitext... Any ideas?

Comment: @Soo, what type is your Cars menu item? When I create a menu in the designer my Cars menu is a ToolStripMenuItem.

Comment: See also here for examples on wiring up events https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608102/how-to-add-things-to-a-menustrip-programatically